# Cordova prepare takes long time after v7 upgrade

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, cordova-cli

After upgrading to cordova v7 plugins are downloaded with cordova-fetch by default when using cordova prepare. In v7 this could be overridden by using `--no-fetch`. The no-fetch flag has been dropped since cordova v8 though.

Installing the plugins took seconds with v6 and v7 with the no-fetch flag, but now it takes around 10 minutes for the same number of plugins (around 20).

Is there no way to get the plugins in a similar amount of time as v6 and v7 when using cordova v8?

Are we supposed to check in the plugins so that we don't download them every build now?